# How to group these vertices by its "level"

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have many graphs and I want to group all vertices by its "level",but I don't know how to define the "level" exactly,just by its topological order to discern they.I give some example in follow and label its "level".

[image]

All of the `graphs` is a [**In directed acyclic graphs**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction#In_directed_acyclic_graphs) got by [TransitiveReductionGraph](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransitiveReductionGraph.html),and its vertex name is difference.

### Question

How to group **vertices in all graphs** by its "level"?The expected result is:

```
{{"swallow","allowance","shallow",100,"thought","drought","detective",1},
{"wallow",101,"ought","rough","detect",2,3},{"allow",102,103,4},{104,5},{105}}
```

### Current try

```
graphs=(Uncompress@*FromCharacterCode@*Flatten@*(ImageData[#1, "Byte"] &)@*
   Import)["http://ooo.0o0.ooo/2016/11/24/58374fe8b5196.png"];
```

For `graphs[[1]]` I can get such result:

```
Function[g, 
  DeleteDuplicates /@ 
   Flatten[VertexOutComponent[g, #] & /@ 
     VertexList[g, _?(VertexInDegree[g, #] == 0 &)], {2}]]@graphs[[1]]
```

> {{swallow,allowance,shallow},{wallow,allow},{allow}}

Of course,in `graphs[[1]]` I want to get `{{swallow,allowance,shallow},{wallow},{allow}}`.How to refine this code for all `graphs`?

Comment: I think it's not going to be possible to define the level uniquely ... I mean more than one level assignment may be a good solution.  Nice question, +1!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rule = Flatten[MapIndexed[Thread[# -> #2[[1]]] &, #] & /@ 
       (Quiet[NestWhileList[{vl = VertexList[#[[2]], _?(Function[v, 
                 VertexInDegree[#[[2]], v] == 0])], VertexDelete[#[[2]], vl]} &, {{}, #}, 
        #[[2, 0]] =!=  VertexDelete &]][[2 ;; -2, 1]] & /@ graphs)];

allvertices = Join @@ (VertexList /@ graphs);

Pick[allvertices, allvertices /. rule, #] & /@ Range[Max[rule[[All, -1]]]]
```

> {{"swallow", "allowance", "shallow", 100, "thought", "drought", "detective", 1},
>   {"wallow", 101, "ought", "rough", "detect", 2, 3},
>   {"allow", 102, 103, 4},
>   {104, 5},
>   {105}}